# OpsCenter 6.7.7 won't manage an existant cassandra cluster (dse 6.7.7) running on: redhat 7.6 Maipo

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, opscenter

I encountered an issue with my fresh new OpsCenter 6.7.7; when I click "manage an existing" cluster I received the following error message:

```
Meld execution failed: OS platform (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, 7.7, Maipo) is not supported for DSE . If absolutely necessary, this can be turned off with the disable_platform_check configuration setting. {:name "myserver.domain.name", . . .
```

I add the following to my opscenterd.conf:

```
[lifecycle_manager]
disable_platform_check =  False
```

But unfortunately this does fix the agent complain but NOT the LCM management issue :/

Any advice is welcome.

kr,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to "fix" this issue, I had to update the OpsCenter definitions; I simply follow the official procedure [Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/configure/opscDefnsConfigProps.html).

Basically:

- stop opscenter service
- backup your current definition folder (in case of rollbackup but not mandatory)
- download the latest  [definition.tar.gz archive](https://opscenter.datastax.com/definitions/6.1.0/definition_files.tgz)
- extract the archige
- start opscenter service

And that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have [latest definitions downloaded](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.7/opsc/configure/opscDefnsConfigProps.html).

Your file `platforms.edn` (in `/var/lib/opscenter/definitions` in package install) should contain following information:

```
 "5.1.0" {"debian" ["8.x" "9.x"]
          "ubuntu" ["12.04" "14.04" "16.04" "18.04"]
          "red hat enterprise" ["6.7.x" "6.8.x" "6.9.x" "6.10.x" "7.1.x" "7.2.x"
                                "7.3.x" "7.4.x" "7.5.x" "7.6.x" "7.7.x"]
          "oracle" ["6.9.x" "7.4.x" "7.6.x"]
          "centos" ["6.7.x" "6.8.x" "6.9.x" "6.10.x" "7.1.x" "7.2.x" "7.3.x"
                    "7.4.x" "7.5.x" "7.6.x" "7.7.x"]
          "amazon" ["2016.09" "2017.03" "2017.09" "2018.09" "2"]}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing and it fixed my issue but I didn't take the time to post it; Anyway, thanks for you help :)